# What is the purpose of the RVM binary if it can be run as a function?

Tags: ruby, rvm

I've recently started using Ruby and was told to look into using RVM. I'm currently trying to understand how it operates but as far as I can tell from the website it can be run either as a binary or as a function in the shell by modifying .bash_profile.

What are the binaries for? I noticed they got installed to `~/bin`, which felt sort of messy, and they did not seem to be invoked when using the `rvm` command. Are the binaries even needed when running RVM as a shell function?

Comment: RVM installs its binaries into `~/.rvm/bin`. Try `which rvm` and you'll see its in your `~/.rvm/bin/rvm`. It puts everything into its own sandbox so you can very cleanly blow it all away if you want.

Comment: In my Ubuntu 10.04, the `rvm` *script* is in both `~/bin` and `~/.rvm/bin` directories, though `which rvm` points to the one in `~/.rvm/bin`. I don't know what/where the `rvm` binary is and what it is called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is normal and desirable for users of unix to put binaries in ~/bin (you would normally add that to your `$PATH`), so don't feel like it's messy to install stuff there.

That said, ~/bin/rvm is a script that will let you run rvm commands (like install), but is unable to edit your shell's environment (like all programs).  Commands that need to edit the environment (like use), would not be possible without the rvm function.  Not being super familiar with rvm, I am guessing the ~/bin/rvm exists for people that don't want to include the rvm stuff in all their shells.  AFAICT, you don't need any of the stuff rvm puts in ~/bin if you are going to alter your ~/.bashrc as recommended.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. I did not know about ~/bin. I admit I am new to the Unix stuff but I've been putting most things in /usr/local/bin. What is the difference between that and ~/bin?

Comment: @Jens Ljungblad: /usr/local/bin is the appropriate place to put stuff that all users of your system would be interested in (I suspect the site-wide install of rvm would install there).  ~/bin would be utilities that are specific to you (a user-installed rvm), helper scripts you have written for yourself, etc.